# radio click not showing

Tags: jquery

How do i check to see if a radio button is clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#rad").click(function() {
        var radio = $("#rad input:checked");
        if(radio == 0)
        {
            alert($(this).data('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

[html]

```
<input type="radio" data-id='1' name="default" class="rad" value="1">
<input type="radio" data-id='2' name="default" class="rad" value="1">
<input type="radio" data-id='3' name="default" class="rad" value="1">
<input type="radio" data-id='4' name="default" class="rad" value="1">
<input type="radio" data-id='5' name="default" class="rad" value="1">
```

Comment: Did the below answers helped you ?

Answer (score 5):

In the code `rad` is class not `id` so use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to bind event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qMxGU/)**

*Change*

```
$("#rad")
```

*To*

```
$(".rad")
```

When ever you click a `radio` button it is check so you do not need to verify it again, and `$(this)` represents source of event you can use it directly, your code would be

```
$(".rad").click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get your radio buttons by name and then check to see which one is clicked. like this,

```
    $(function() {
    $('input[name="default"]').click(function() {
     var getID = $(this).attr('data-id');
      alert(getID);
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be selecting element via class selector instead of id selector first, then you check for the checked status if you need but since you click it its always gonna be checked.

after that use `.attr()` method to get the `data-id` attributes data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".rad").click(function() {
        if($(".rad").is(":checked")) { // not necessarily needed
            alert($(this).attr('data-id')); // use data-id inside .attr()
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### **[Check here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gUEaM/)**

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.rad', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Make sure that you have **[1.7+ Jquery](http://jqapi.ru/)**

[image]

**Alternative - 1**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rad').bind('click', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```

**Alternative - 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rad').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });    
});
```